# Find the difference between times in the hour and min format using pig script

Tags: apache-pig

I have a sheet that has starting time and end time column. I want to find only the columns that has difference more than 15 minutes using pig script. Kindly help me and load that in another relation.

```
| start-time | end-time |
-------------------------
| 1157       | 1220     |
| 1300       | 1400     |
| 1310       | 1315     |
| 757        | 833      |
```

Answer (score 0):

Before loading the data, format the time column with a leading `0` incase of single digit hours,

```
data = load '/data.txt' using PigStorage(' ') as (start:chararray, end:chararray);
```

Compute the time difference using [`MinutesBetween`](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#minutes-between):

```
time_diff = foreach data generate start, end, MinutesBetween(ToDate(end, 'HHmm'), ToDate(start, 'HHmm')) as difference;
```

Then filter the result on condition:

```
filtered = filter time_diff by difference > 15;

dump filtered;
(1157,1220,23)
(1300,1400,60)
(0757,0833,36)
```

Comment: If we can add 'hmm', in ToDate method we dont have to add leading zero am I correct.

Comment: It will not work if you have two digits in hours place.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we can use the solution below to pad missing zeros

You can solve this problem in 3 ways.
Option1: If you installed pig 0.14 version then try this approach

input

```
2014    11      12
2013    01      02
2012    12      3
2011    5       24
2010    1       1
PigScript:

A = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage() AS(year:int,month:int,date:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE SPRINTF('%04d-%02d-%02d',year,month,date) AS (finaldate:chararray);
```